# Issue with Big Decimal

Tags: json, groovy, bigdecimal

I am setting the scale and rounding decimal numbers for the data in json using Big Deciaml.

Sample data inside json:

```
{"dataMap":{"DATE":"20071.0","mean":"20225.08483315143","ByGroup":"Mean"}
```

The code to set scale, round and replaced the original number with new -

```
 //body - JSON body as String 
    //rndNumber - scale OR digits required after dedcimal
    private static String roundDecimalNumbers(def body, int rndNumber)
        {
            def ids = body =~ /[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?/

            String number
            double dblNumber
            BigDecimal dec
            double newNumber
            (0..<ids.count).each
            {
                number = ids[it].toString()
                dec = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(number)).setScale(rndNumber, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).stripTrailingZeros()
                body = body.toString().replace(number, dec.toString()) //replacing the orignial number with the scaled and rounded number 
            }
            return body.toString()
        }
```

For some of the instances of decimal numbers I am getting exception like below 
e.g. for the sample data mentioned above I get error -

> java.lang.AssertionError:data[rowNumber=4].dataMap.data[rowNumber=97].dataMap.mean
>   Expected: 202258483315145 got: 202258483315143
>
> Other similar exception -  aused by: java.lang.AssertionError:
>   data[rowNumber=2].dataMap.data[rowNumber=73].dataMap.lower1 Expected:
>   -354402976665825
>        got: -354402976665821

At the same time majority of the numbers are getting scaled, rounded and replaced fine in the same json like -

```
{"dataMap":{"DATE":"19854","mean":"21778.4088","ByGroup":"Mean"},"rowNumber":66},{"dataMap":{"DATE":"19861","mean":"21547.0865","ByGroup":"Mean"},"rowNumber":67}
```

I am unable to figure out why there is issue with some particular numbers. Kindly help.

Comment: No idea what your assertions are, but from `Expected: 202258483315145 got: 202258483315143`, and the data above, the "expected" looks wrong, and the "actual" looks right...  Also, you could use jsonslurper, and avoid parsing json with regular expressions

Comment: you have quite tricky algorithm. for example with this body: `{"a":1.29,"b":-1.29}` and rndNumber=1 the expected response should be `{"a":1.2,"b":-1.3}`. but actual response: `{"a":1.2,"b":-1.2}` because the replacement for `a` will also replace value for `b`.